# Python turtle assignment pleasehelp

Tags: python

I need to create a function called SpinPolygon that will do what the instruction says. I am a noob coder.

SpinPolygon(Turtle, sides, angle, length, repeat):  Draws the polygon number of times while turn polygon by the angle on the left each time.   Your program needs to ask number of sides, length of the side and number of rotations from the user)  Below is a sample image for rotating 5 times.

[image]

I have this so far for the rest of my program:`

```
import turtle

stage = turtle.Screen() # set stage
stage.title("Shapes") # name stage
sides = int(input("Please enter number of sides:"))
length = int(input("Please enter length of side:"))
sfactor = float(input("Please enter the scale factor:"))
copies = int(input("Please enter number of copies:"))
repeat = int(input("Please enter number of times to repeat the shape:"))

def angle(sides):
    sum_of_angles = (sides - 2) * 180
    exterior_angle = sum_of_angles / sides
    angle = 180 - exterior_angle
    return angle

def drawShape(turtle, sides, length):
    for i in range(sides):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(angle(sides))

def SpinPolygon(Turtle, sides, angle, length, repeat):
    print("idk")

def ScalePolygon(turtle, sides, length, sfactor, number):
    for i in range(number):
        drawShape(turtle, sides, length)
        length *= sfactor
    turtle.done()

ScalePolygon(turtle, sides, length, sfactor, copies)
```

Comment: as fo me first you should calculate angles in shape and angles in rotation - as I rember first can be `360 / sides` and second `360 / repeat` - and later send all to SpinPolygon. and draw single Shape (using first angle), next rotate turtle (using second angle), rescale sides, and do all again (`repeat` times)

Comment: description doesn't mention `sfactor` and `copies`. You ask for too many elements. And you should start runiing at `SpinPolygon`, not `ScalePolygon`. You don't even need `ScalePolygon` because description doesn't mention `sfactor`.

Answer (score 0):

Description doesn't mention to ask for `sfactor`, `copies` and even for `angle`.
You ask for too many elements.

Function `angle` can be reduced to `angle = 360 / sides`

You should start with `SpinPolygon`, not `ScalePolygon`.
And you don't even need `ScalePolygon` because description doesn't mention `sfactor`.

```
import turtle

# --- functions ---

def drawShape(turtle, sides, length):
    shape_angle = 360 / sides
    for i in range(sides):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(shape_angle)

def SpinPolygon(turtle, sides, angle, length, repeat):
    for i in range(repeat):
        drawShape(turtle, sides, length)
        turtle.left(angle)

# --- main ---

stage = turtle.Screen()
stage.title("Shapes")

sides  = 5    #int(input("number of sides: "))
length = 100  #int(input("length of side: "))
repeat = 5    #int(input("number of rotations: "))

angle  = 360/repeat

SpinPolygon(turtle, sides, angle, length, repeat)

turtle.done()
```

Result for `sides = 5`:

[image]

Result for `sides = 4`:

[image]

Result for `sides = 8, length = 50, repeat = 15`:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Code with extra `sfactor`

```
import turtle

# --- functions ---

def drawShape(turtle, sides, length):
    shape_angle = 360 / sides
    for i in range(sides):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(shape_angle)

def SpinPolygon(Turtle, sides, angle, length, repeat, sfactor):
    for i in range(repeat):
        drawShape(turtle, sides, length)
        turtle.left(angle)
        length *= sfactor

# --- main ---

stage = turtle.Screen()
stage.title("Shapes")

sides   = 8    #int(input("number of sides: "))
length  = 50   #int(input("length of side: "))
repeat  = 15   #int(input("number of rotations: "))
sfactor = 0.9  #float(input("sfactor: "))

angle  = 360/repeat   

SpinPolygon(turtle, sides, angle, length, repeat, sfactor)

turtle.done()
```

Result for `sides = 8, length = 50, repeat = 15` and `sfactor = 0.9`:

[image]